# Grant Permissions for Directory using Powershell with icacls

Tags: powershell, cmd, directory, windows-server-2012, icacls

i want to set grant Permissions to a ftp-user for a directory on Windows Server 2012R2 Core Installation. Im administrating the system over Powershell.

The Command:

```
icacls "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite" /grant ftp_user1:(OI)(CI)F
```

works well when i put it in the command prompt wich i get when  i logon the server over hyper-V-Console. But i want to set it up over PSRemote and later using the same commands in a script... so, if use the icacls command, the parser has Problems and the command does not work.

Is there a way to bring CMD Commands in Powershell 100% working?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you need to put your parameters into an array of strings and pass the array as params. I had a similar issue calling `robocopy` from powershell.

Try this:

```
$params = @("c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite","/grant","ftp_user1:(OI)(CI)F")
icacls $params
```

Comment: Using an array is optional, simply putting quotes around the arguments should suffice: `icacls "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite" "/grant" "ftp_user1:(OI)(CI)F"`

Comment: Fair enough, I found it easier with robocopy to do an array but you make a fair point :-)